# Multiple Solid Color Backgrounds in CSS

Tags: css, background, center

I'm trying to figure out more about CSS backgrounds just for the experience, and I've come to a little snafu. I want to have 2 backgrounds, one a very dark grey (almost black) then a opaque white one in front of it. If I use posiiton:fixed; then I can't set margin:auto to center the opaque box, which I only want to take up 65% of the width. A picture is worth a thousand words, so a page must be worth 10,000.

www.nashread.com/template2

Here's the CSS for the opaque background (the one that takes up 65%)

```
#subbackground
{
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    opacity: .2;
    margin:auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

And here's the solid background:

```
#background
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Basically I want overlapping backgrounds and one to only take up 65% of the width. position:absolute doesn't work, because then if you have to scroll down there will be no opaque background. Unless I could do something with background-repeat: reapeat-y; or something like that?

Thanks, Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:fixed` can achieve centering by:

```
margin-left:-32.5%;
width:65%;
left:50%;
position:fixed;
```

Comment: Thanks :] Worked like a charm.

Comment: @TonyBlackburn You are welcome! This is the my first comment received in SOF~